How to Notify Change is needed on Worksheet activation If Today is Monday and specific cell is not blank?
This code works. I just wanted to know if there is any any furthur simplification that can be done to improve it.
Thank you for any feedback to help me improve.
*resourcse have been provided as well
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983649/how-do-i-express-if-value-is-not-empty-in-the-vba-language

If Format(Now(), "DDD") = "Mon" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("D4").Value <> "" Then
'run monday code
MsgBox "Remember to Clear out the Charts. It's a new week"

End If

End Sub

Here is also a secondary code i created to partner with it, as part of a daily running macro. (Not everyone on the team uses the macros on the files).
I would also like any feedback on how to improve.
'https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-if-current-time-is-5pm-then.667426/
currentHour = DatePart("h", Time)
If Format(Now(), "DDD") = "Mon" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("G4").Value <> "" Then
Sheets("Charts").Select
Range("C4:G12,C17:G25,C30:G38").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("T16").Select
End If
If Format(Now(), "DDD") = "Fri" And currentHour > 10 And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("G4").Value <> "" Then
Sheets("Charts").Select
Range("C4:G12,C17:G25,C30:G38").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("T16").Select
End If

If Format(Now(), "DDD") = "Sat" Or Format(Now(), "DDD") = "Sun" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("G4").Value <> "" Then
Sheets("Charts").Select
Range("C4:G12,C17:G25,C30:G38").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("T16").Select
End If


did addittional reserach for maybe specific timing - in helps that if its the beginning of the hour.
link
try adding line 1, then changing the If function to line 2
code
TimeIs = TimeValue(Time)
If Format(Now(), "DDD") = "Fri" And TimeIs > "10:01:00" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("G4").Value <> "" Then
